# Is it possible to output all the code I've typed into the console in the last session?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to output all the code I've typed into the console in the last session?
just the code, without the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up a new web inspector while in the current inspector (ctrl+shift+j, they removed recursive inspect element), then do this in the new inspector:

```
console.dir(WebInspector.consoleView.prompt._suggestBox._textPrompt._data)
```

Just to be clear, you don't run this in the inspector for the page. You run this in the inspector's inspector. I.E:

**Your inspector must also be undocked**, otherwise it will just go to the console tab of the current inspector instead of opening a new inspector that inspects the current inspector.

[image]

Comment: Just to add (also, my apologies to anybody who think the following is old news):  To undock the inspector, see that fat-bordered rectangle at the bottom right of Esailija's screenshot?  That's the "dock/undock" button, currently showing "undocked".  When the inspector is docked you will see two overlapping rectangles in its place.

Comment: @user1294129 thank you for the question, otherwise I wouldn't have hacked around to find out about this. I have favorited the question so I can find the snippet easily when I need it :P

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something called [command line history](http://getfirebug.com/commandline/) of Firebug.

> The command line maintains its own history of executed expressions and
>   so, you can easily go back and execute an expression again. Just use
>   up & down arrows or click on the red button on the left side of the
>   command line to see a history popup with all entries. Links and
>   Elsewhere